# Why is SciPy acting very differently in IPython and Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy, ipython

I wrote this test script:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg

n = 130
r = np.array(np.random.normal(size=(n, n)), dtype=np.float32)
e = scipy.linalg.eig(r, left=False, right=False)
print e.mean()
```

Running it using IPython, the code always succeeds in a fraction of a second (I tried it about a dozen times)

With Python, the code **always** fails to converge (or just hangs, for some larger `n`) with a message like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strange.py", line 6, in <module>
    e = scipy.linalg.eig(r, left=False, right=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp.py", line 179, in eig
    "with order >= %d have converged)" % info)
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: eig algorithm did not converge (only eigenvalues with order >= 130 have converged)
```

What explains this difference in the behavior of Python and IPython? The relevant software versions are:

- Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit
- Numpy 1.6.1
- SciPy 0.9.0
- Python 2.7.3
- IPython  0.12.1

**Edit**

I observed this behavior only with single precision and `n >= 130`. If `n = 129`, the code works in both Python and IPython.

Adding `np.random.seed(1234)` after the `import`s gives the same result: IPython converges, while Python does not.

`scipy.linalg.__file__ = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.pyc'` in both. Despite this, I would guess that IPython and Python somehow manage to pull in different `LAPACK` versions, but how?

The way I noticed this oddity is that I was experimenting in IPython, and then pasting the code into a `*.py` file that I run with Python. You can imagine how confused I was for a while.

**Edit 2**.

`np.geterr()` is `{'divide': 'warn', 'invalid': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore'}` in both Python and IPython

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/libblas.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jun 29 18:21 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so -> /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so
```

Comment: Dunno if this has anything to do with your problem (since I'm clueless about what the real problem is), but why do you have that `np.array` call converting the random sample to `float32`?

Comment: BTW if this `(-0.0227526994852+0j)` is the expected output it runs fine on my windows 32-bit machine with python 2.7, can you confirm this is the expected output??

Comment: By the way, why numpy and scipy are so outdated?

Comment: oops guess the output is random BTW it runs in less than a fraction of a second on numpy 1.7.1 and scipy 0.12.0

Comment: you do not seed the random number generator (`np.seed(1234)`).

Comment: @alko: Those are the versions in the Ubuntu 12.04 repository.

Comment: What's the output of `ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_flapack.so`? Is it different if you run it from inside ipython (prefix with `!`)?

Comment: what is the output of: `np.geterr()`? importing pandas, e.g. in your ipython profile, changes the error handling to ignore. which blas are you using (ls -l /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3)

Comment: @Dougal I tried it with `flapack.so` (I don't have `_flapack.so` in that directory). The results are identical from the shell and IPython, except for the numbers in the parentheses - I verified it in `vimdiff`.

Comment: @jtaylor Please see "edit 2".

Comment: @MaxB Can you check for differences in environment variables? e.g. print `os.environ` from both. It seems like you're using openblas, and it might have different environment variables set to control things like multithreading.

Comment: @Dougal I gave in to peer pressure to upgrade iPython, NumPy and SciPy, so I wiped them, and installed the latest versions from source instead of Ubuntu 12.04. I don't seem have this problem anymore. Thanks to everyone for trying to help!

Comment: No repro for me on 13.10

Comment: I found that adding this import to the plain python version of the code made the results match: `from numpy.dual import register_func`.

Comment: @MaxB might want to mark that as an answer. So do you mean you used something along the lines of `apt-get remove python-numpy python-scipy ipython  && pip install scipy numpy ipython` ?

Comment: @Shurane upon further investigation, the only solution I found was to not use these SciPy functions, and use the equivalent NumPy functions

Comment: I made a virtual Ubuntu 12.04 64bit machine and installed the cited versions of Numpy, SciPy, Python, and IPython, and both versions of the script worked in both ipython and python (see `https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/8173209`). However, after installing `libopenblas-base`, only the ipython one worked, as described.

Comment: for me both ipython and python works. MaxB, if your problem is solved, you can mark it as solved.

Comment: I noticed, that dynamic cross-linking with openBLAS seems to be causing some problems when using with numpy - not sure if this is one of them. I ran into problems concerning core affinity when using numpy together with multiprocessing. These two cases MIGHT be somehow linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** is different when you are using IPython. This could result in using different libraries. You can check this in both Python and IPython and see if they are identical:

```
import os
print os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
```